# glMatrix - mat4 not defined

Tags: webgl, gl-matrix

*Hi,
I downloaded* toji-gl-matrix-21b745f.

*I copied the file* dist/gl-matrix-min.js *inside the web-root folder.*

*In index.html i have:*

```
<script src="gl-matrix-min.js"></script>
<script src="main.js" defer></script>
```

*And inside in* main.js *i use:*

```
const matrix = mat4.create();
```

*Result is:*  **ReferenceError: mat4 is not defined**

I already tried glMatrix.mat4 but result is the same.

I don't understand the error.
Can someone help me.
Thx in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gl-matrix is not included properly in webgl application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66147508/gl-matrix-is-not-included-properly-in-webgl-application). Otherwise check the network tab to see if the file is actually found.

Comment: Did you ever find your answer?

Comment: I tried adding <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.8.1/gl-matrix-min.js"> inside my index.html and received the error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: You load plain JS - in Ver 3 access is glMatrix.vec3 ...

Answer (score 2):

Destructuring only gives you objects but no methods in VS Code intellisense.

I downloaded the source files rather then the dist files, put them in a folder, and imported from the `index.js` file like:

```
import { mat2, mat2d, mat3, mat4, quat, quat2, vec2, vec3, vec4, } from "./index.js";
```

These source files are **large** so you will want to switch out for "minified" version in production, switch the above for this then:

```
import "./gl-matrix-min.js";
const { mat2, mat2d, mat4, mat3, quat, quat2, vec2, vec3, vec4 } = glMatrix;
```

Full code completion hints:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

see this:https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.8.1/gl-matrix-min.js
I think you should include this file which contain mat4 object.

Comment: I tried adding `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.8.1/gl-matrix-min.js">` inside my index.html and received the error: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Answer (score 0):

If you use last version of gl-matrix library and you load it on normal way (direct not from npm build etc..) then use this before calling glMatrix funcs ... :

Put intro global space and you program will works fine.

```js
window.mat4 = glMatrix.mat4
window.mat2 = glMatrix.mat2
window.mat2d= glMatrix.mat2d
window.mat3= glMatrix.mat3
window.mat4= glMatrix.mat4
window.quat= glMatrix.quat
window.quat2= glMatrix.quat2
window.vec2= glMatrix.vec2
window.vec3= glMatrix.vec3
window.vec4= glMatrix.vec4
```